# Getting Error in SQL as Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am using below statement to extract the data but getting error as **'Error converting data type varchar to float.'**

```
select Docket_No, Order_No, Ven_cd, Ven_name, Order_Type, DSP, Manifest_Id, Order_Date, Inv_Out_Date from ORDERDATA 
WHERE Docket_No = '123456'
```

Please help me

I am using SQL server management 2016

Comment: Is number `123456` only example or your original condition? Is `Docket_No` `float` column?

Comment: yes its just an example and yes docket no is float column

Comment: Ok, so you are probably try to convert number with comma to `float` number. Replace comma with dot. `123,45` to `123.45`.

Comment: Thanks @Rokuto but it all gone bouncer on me. Please be more specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across this issue. 
In this case, SQL knows that its(docket_no) of float data type. When you try to concatenate the a float value to a string this error occurs.

If you can specify, how you have done the concatenation then i will try to tell where the error occurs.

Thanks

Comment: Actually the database i had create that i had imported from access and in Design mode it is showing as Float

Comment: Ok then..Here docket_no is of float data type. So try using cast to convert data type of float to varchar.    eg: CAST(CAST(docket_no AS NUMERIC(30)) AS VARCHAR(100))

Comment: Nope still getting the same error `select CAST(CAST(Docket_no AS NUMERIC(30)) AS VARCHAR(100)),Order_No, Ven_cd, Ven_name, Order_Type, DSP, Manifest_Id, Order_Date, Inv_Out_Date from ORDERDATA 
WHERE Docket_No = 'S1212411035694'`

Comment: SELECT *
FROM ORDERDATA
WHERE CAST(CAST(docket_no AS NUMERIC(30)) AS VARCHAR(100)) = '12';  This is working for me

Comment: okay it is working but it took 33 secs to retrieve the output of single value. is that okay?

Comment: Yae..No issues.